# Declare namespaces within XPath expression

Tags: c#, .net, xpath, xml-namespaces, xelement

My application needs to evaluate XPath expression against some XML data. Expression is provided by user at runtime. So, I cannot create `XmlNamespaceManager` to pass to `XPathEvaluate` because I don't know prefixes and namespaces at compile time.

**Is there any possibility to specify namespaces declaration within xpath expression?**

---

#### Answers to comments:

1. XML data has one default namespace but there can be nested elements with any namespaces. User knows namespaces of the data he works with.
2. User-provided xpath expression is to be evaluated against many XML documents, and every document can have its own prefixes for the same namespaces.

Comment: Are there multiple namespaces in the target XML document? And do you control its content or is it user-supplied?

Comment: See question, I have answered there.

Comment: You wrote *I cannot create `XmlNamespaceManager` to pass to `XPathEvaluate` because I don't know prefixes and namespaces at compile time*. That's wrong. All those XPath visualizers do that with no problem.

Comment: I've got your idea, @Alejandro: to let user specify namespaces and prefixes somewhere near xpath expression. Probably, that's the way I'll go. However, I conclude that there is no way to declare namespace using xpath expression.

Comment: Yes, as a hosted language, there is no way for an XPath expression to change XPath engine invocation context. That's a function of the host language.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know any way to define a namespace prefix in an XPath expression.

But you *can* write the XPath expression to be agnostic of namespace-prefixes by using local-name() and namespace-uri() functions where appropriate.

*Or* if you know the XML-namespaces in advance, you can register an arbitrary prefix for them in the XmlNamespaceManager and tell your user to use that prefix in the XPath expression. It doesn't matter if the XML document itself registers a different prefix or no prefix at all. Path resolution is based on the namespace alone, not on the prefix.

Another option would be to scan the document at runtime (use XmlReader for low resource overhead if you haven't loaded it already) and then add the used mappings in the document in the XmlNamespaceManager. I'm not sure if you can get the namespaces and prefixes from XmlDocument, but I see no direct method to do it. It's easy with XmlReader though, since it exposes NamespaceURI and Prefix members for each node.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of `namespace-uri()` approach. However, expression would be too complicated then. And I don't know namespaces in advance.

Comment: @Anton: Maybe you can scan the XML document with XmlReader or something for any used namespaces, register them generically like "n1", "n2" and so on and tell your user about this mapping in advance?

Comment: @Anton: Wait a minute. If you can do that you can also use the same prefix as in the document. Stupid me :-). I'll amend my answer.

Comment: @TToni: Quite interesting! Unfortunately, user-provided xpath expression is to be evaluated against many XML documents, and there is no guarantee that every document uses the same prefixes.

Comment: @Anton: So how will the user decide what prefix she wants to use in her XPath? If she tries to use prefixes based on one document, her path will be useless on another document unless *you* provide a coherent prefix/namespace mapping for all docs. If that's not possible either, the user will have to work without prefixes.

Comment: @TToni, user definitely knows namespaces. She can use any prefix she wants. You said yourself: "Path resolution is based on the namespace alone, not on the prefix."

Comment: @Anton: Correction: She can use any namespace prefix that *you* defined. So if she wants to use prefixes, you have to have some kind of agreement on how the mapping will occur. Either you pre-scan the documents and tell her, or maybe you know *some* namespaces in advance and for those you can define well-known prefixes while for others she has to work without prefixes, or any combination of that. There are several options available to you, you have to choose which is the most viable.

Comment: Accepting as the most complete answer.

Answer (score 6):

**If the same prefix can be bound to different namespaces and prefixes aren't known in advance, then the only pure XPath way to specify such expressions is to use this form of referring to elements**:

```
someName[namespace-uri() = 'exactNamespace']
```

**So, a particular XPath expression would be**:

```
/*/a[namespace-uri() = 'defaultNS']/b[namespace-uri() = 'NSB']
                                         /c[namespace-uri() = 'defaultNS']
```

Comment: As the author of XPath Visualizer, I think you can answer how to register a namespace URI binding at runtime...

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes, but this cannot be done in pure XPath -- which I said. As we both well know, beyound XPath there are many ways to do this -- dependent on th particular XPath engine and host language being used.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any possibility to specify namespaces declaration within xpath expression?

The answer is no - it's always done in the calling environment (which is actually more flexible).

An alternative would be to use XQuery, which does allow declaring namespaces in the query prolog.

**UPDATE (2020)**

In XPath 3.1 you can use the syntax `/*/Q{http://my-namespace}a`.

Sadly, though, if you're still using Microsoft software, then the situation hasn't changed since 2011 - you're still stuck with XPath 1.0 with all its shortcomings.

Comment: XQuery prolog is exactly what I dream of. But I haven't found built-in  XQuery functionality in .NET

Comment: @Anton: In that case XQSharp (http://www.xqsharp.com/xqsharp/about.htm) might be another alternative.

Comment: I have searched for xquery implementations already. XQsharp is not the case because of its license.

Comment: To be fair, it's only more flexible when you have access and control over the calling environment. If you are only able to provide an XPath but no namespaces (obviously a poor design, but alas, enterprise software), the XPath gets much messier than if an XPath prolog declaration were supported.