# Check whether XML satisfies user-supplied predicate

Tags: .net, xml, xpath, xml-namespaces

Came from [Declare namespaces within XPath expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861262/declare-namespaces-within-xpath-expression)

Simplified task:

- There is a lot of XML files of different structure with namespaces
- User defines several expressions in a text form
- The expressions are applied to each XML file giving the result: yes or no

**What technology should I use for for this task in .NET 3.5 <s>without using third-party libraries</s>?**

Candidates:

- XPath. *Is not the preferred case since there is no simple way to specify namespaces within XPath expression*.
- ...

**Update:**

I have realized that actually the question is: **Is there a way except XPath?**

Schematron is the only suggestion at the moment.

Comment: I agree with [Dr. Kay](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870790/check-whether-xml-satisfies-user-supplied-predicate/4872355#4872355): if you are asserting node existence, then you should use a well known validation tool like [Schematron](http://www.schematron.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraint "without using third-party libraries" seems an odd one: most people these days are trying to maximize code reuse.

Without that constraints, I would say Schematron is the answer. It does exactly what you are looking for.

It's also possible to achieve the same effect using an XSLT stylesheet to define the validation rules - but you end up reinventing Schematron.

Comment: @Michael-Kay: Yes, this question is rather weird. The OP is telling us of evaluating XPath expressions of "end users", who don't have the ability to bind their prefixes to the namespaces that are used in the document; Also the document is re-using the same prefixes with different namespaces. The OP does *not* want the namespace-independent syntax as "too uncomfortable" and is asking if there is any other solution.

Answer (score 1):

> Simplified task:
>
> •There is a lot of XML files of
> different structure with namespaces
>
> •User defines several predicates in a
> text form
>
> •The predicates are applied
> to each XML file giving the result:
> yes or no

**It is not clear what the word "predicates" is intended to mean in the above description.**

I assume that this means: "*XPath expression(s) that evaluate to boolean*"

If this is so, each such individual expression can be evaluated using for example **[XPathNavigator.Evaluate(XPathExpression)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/755fkf1e.aspx)**

The problem of different users using different namespaces needs a centralized solution. One approach, which I recommend is to create and publish a central catalog of namespace prefix to namespace mappings, so that the expression-authors should only use prefixes from this catalogue. All these prefixes will be bound to the respective namespaces before evaluating any XPath expression. The .NET class [**`XmlNamespaceManager`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnamespacemanager.aspx) is very suitable for this purpose. An example how to use `XmlNamespaceManager` together with [**`XpathNavigator.Evaluate()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/755fkf1e.aspx) and [**`XPathNavigator.Select()`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3tk3f03k.aspx) can be found [**here**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xpath.xpathexpression.aspx).

**Very important**: Never evaluate strings containing an XPath expression -- this may result in **[XPath injection](http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XPATH_Injection)**. Always compile the string (for exmple using **[XPathExpression.Compile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms163317.aspx)**()). Even if such discipline is adhered to, evaluating an user-supplied XPath expression may lead to security risks.

Comment: As I have mentioned, there is an inconvenience using namespaces in XPath expression. Looking for another approach.

Comment: @Anton: Yes, you have mentioned that the documents have namespaces -- however this is in no way related to the requirements that follow and seems even unnecessary to mention. If this is not the case, you need to make this clear in your question. It is not realistic to expect a meaningful answer to an ambiguous question. Please edit and define better.

Comment: @Anton - namespaces don't HAVE to be used in XPATH expressions. It is possible to use namespace-agnostic XPATH(e.g. `/*[local-name()='foo']`), or to invert the namespace checks inside of a predicate to avoid having to register the namespaces (e.g. `/*[local-name()='foo' and namespace-uri()='urn:bar']`).It is extremely verbose and more difficult to read/write, but is not impossible. You could even attempt to reverse enginee

Comment: @Mads-Hansen: He was told of this possibility in answers/comments to his previous question, but @Anton rejected this as "too complicated" ...

Answer (score 0):

If the namespaces are an "issue", you could always:

1. Pre-process the XML files using a modified identity transform to generate an XML file with nodes that are not bound to a particular namespace
2. Then evaluate the user provided XPATH against the modified XML
3. Return the result

**Do note** that while this makes the XPATH creation and evaluation more simple, it completely circumvents the reason for namespaces and **you may get ambiguous matches for elements/attributes from another namespace, and return incorrect results**.

Comment: Thanks, but namespaces are important in my case.